# Swift Picker binding doesn't write to model

Tags: swift, swiftui, binding

In my first swift app, a data binding for a `Picker` doesn't work in the direction view to model.

```
class AppConfig: ObservableObject
{
    var _bpm: UInt = 115
    
    var bpm: String {
        get { return String(_bpm) }
        set { _bpm = UInt(newValue) ?? 0 }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var midiCtrl = MidiControl()
    @StateObject var appConfig = AppConfig()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            Grid(alignment: .leadingLastTextBaseline) {
                GridRow {
                    Label("BPM", systemImage: "")
                        .gridColumnAlignment(.trailing)
                    Picker("Picker", selection: $appConfig.bpm) {
                        ForEach((80...120).reversed(), id: \.self) { idx in
                            Text(String(idx)).tag(String(idx))
                        }
                    }
                }
                Divider()
            }.padding()
        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear() {
            midiCtrl.openMidi()
        }
        .onDisappear() {
            midiCtrl.closeMidi()
        }
        .environmentObject(midiCtrl)
    }
}
```

Initially, the picker has the correct value preselected (115).

However, when I try to change the value using the picker, nothing happens.

I thought the binding in Swift UI using the `selection: $variable` syntax is a two way binding. Am I wrong? Do you manually have to add event handlers for something like `selectionChanged`?

I also tried `@Published` and `@ObservedObject`, but I'm getting weird compiler errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `@Published` when you have a property that should trigger a view update in a class that conforms to `ObservableObject`

Here I simplified it and worked directly with `UInt`

```
class AppConfig: ObservableObject {
    @Published var bpm: UInt = 115
}
```

Then adjust the view (again simplified)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var appConfig = AppConfig()

    var body: some View {
        Picker("Picker", selection: $appConfig.bpm) {
            ForEach((UInt(80)...UInt(120)).reversed(), id: \.self) { idx in
                Text(idx.formatted()).tag(idx)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But if I add `@Published` to the `bpm` property, I get a bunch of compiler errors. 1.) `AppConfig` has no initializers 2.) invalid redeclaration of synthesized property `_bpm` 3.) Property wrapper cannot be applied to computed property. :O - I understand your simplified version without get/set, but is there a way to make `@Published` work with computed properties?

Comment: @mefiX 1. These errors will go away if you use the example provided to you exactly as it stated. You need to rename your property to `bpm` (don't call it `_bpm`), and it needs to have an initial value

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add @Published to the _bmp variable. That should update your view. If you don't want to get rid of the computed property all together as proposed.

Comment: Yep, that was it! It's so funny how I just found it out by lucky accident while trying out the solution by @joakim-danielson